# cache a value during make steps

Tags: makefile

I have the following steps:

```
tag ?= `date +%s`

build:
    docker build -t org/client-api:$(tag) -t org/client-api:latest .

push:
    docker push org/client-api:$(tag)
    docker push org/client-api:latest
```

The `tag` value is being reevaluated if I do `make build push` so the first step passes because the tag is 123123123**1** and the second fails because `tag` now is 123123123**2**.
How can I cache the value of `tag` between steps? I thought that using `?=` would be sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the assignment where you use the shell back single quote operator. The variable `tag` is assigned with the string containing this quote and gets evaluated twice.

I would use `shell` operator (to perform the evaluation once) and `:=` operator (because `date` command will always output something) in the `Makefile`:

```
tag:=$(shell date +%s)

build:
   echo "build: ${tag}"
   sleep 3

push:
   echo "push: ${tag}"
```

Which gives:

```
$ make build push
echo "build: 1510323684"
build: 1510323684
sleep 3
echo "push: 1510323684"
push: 1510323684
```

Ref from the [gnu make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors)